# Update prepared statement not working

Tags: php, sql, pdo

This SQL isn't working and I'm trying to fix it for hours with rowCount() and print_r($array) but no luck.

Appreciate all help!

```
$sql=" UPDATE Listing SET 
        rentStartDate = :rentStartDate,
        rentEndDate = :rentEndDate,
        backyard = :backyard,
        pricePerMonth = :pricePerMonth,
        noOfBathrooms = :noOfBathrooms,
        roomCapacity = :roomCapacity,
        currentNoOfuser = :currentNoOfuser,
        accessToPublicTrans = :accessToPublicTrans,
        parkingSpace = :parkingSpace,
        minimumLengthOfStay = :minimumLengthOfStay 
        WHERE address = :address ";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':address',  $address);  
    $stmt->bindValue(':rentStartDate', $rentStartDate);  
    $stmt->bindValue(':rentEndDate', $rentEndDate);  
    $stmt->bindValue(':backyard', $backyard);  
    $stmt->bindValue(':pricePerMonth', $pricePerMonth);  
    $stmt->bindValue(':noOfBathrooms', $noOfBathrooms);  
    $stmt->bindValue(':roomCapacity', $roomCapacity);  
    $stmt->bindValue(':currentNoOfuser', $currentNoOfuser);  
    $stmt->bindValue(':accessToPublicTrans', $accessToPublicTrans);
    $stmt->bindValue(':parkingSpace', $parkingSpace);
    $stmt->bindValue(':minimumLengthOfStay', $minimumLengthOfStay);       

    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: try turning on error reporting, or putting everything in a try {} catch (PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage(); } block. post the errors if any

Comment: Put your code in a [`try-catch` block](http://pastebin.com/aLcFLxby).

Comment: you can get the error messages for PDO using: [Fetch the SQLSTATE associated with the last operation on the database handle = check the `See Also` section](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php). Will you please edit your question with the connection settings you are using on your PDO connection.

Comment: `bindValue` is using for `PDO statement`. what is your connection settings ?

Comment: Hope you don't have two addresses in different zip codes.

Comment: From your question your trying something with rowcount() and print_r($array)  yet from your code they are not there

Comment: @chapskev I'm only showing a snippet of my code.

Comment: @PhilWalton I used a try catch but didn't get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this like:

```
$sql=" UPDATE Listing SET 
        rentStartDate = ?,
        rentEndDate = ?
        WHERE address = ?";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bind_param('sss',  $rentStartDate,$rentEndDate,$address);  

    $stmt->execute();
```